# how to post and put request in unit testing with front-end angular and back-end node using jasmine and karma?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

I have created one angular project and one node project for add data in SQL workbench.

I can add data in SQL workbench while I am running ng serve from angular project.

while the time of unit testing using jasmine & karma and we run ng test command & its run your test case and we got data in console log but we didn't get data in SQL database.

[api.services.spec.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4svS.png)

[Form.component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owXNk.png)

Can anyone help me for the same?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: unit testing should never call actual database. create mocks

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named 'environment.test.ts' in 'environments' directory and then in 'angular.json' file, check the 'test' block. Add code below:

```
        "fileReplacements": [{
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
        }]
```